# Localhost prompting username and password

Tags: c#, visual-studio, authentication, webforms

I'm currently busy with changes on a solution I'm working on but as soon as I try to run the application I get prompted for a Username and a Password.

[The login that gets prompted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOtRb.jpg)

I have restarted VS and tried running it as an Administrator which didn't work.

I've also attempted to reset the settings ..

> Tools >> Import and export setting >> Reset all settings

I've also tried to find 'NTLM Authentication' under

> > Debug->(Your Proj) Properties->Start Options

But I think this setting is prior to VS 2015.

Any help would be very much appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried logging in with root, or admin or something?

Comment: @Tomm I have, I have also tried to remove windows authentication from the web.config

Comment: I am sorry. I have actually never ever encountered this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem(kicking myself in the head), I recently started using the Beta Version of the new Firefox Quantum browser _ Developer Edition and for some reason this is prompting the login details.

Works perfectly fine on Google Chrome.

Also added

```
<iisExpressSettings windowsAuthentication="enabled" anonymousAuthentication="enabled" useClassicPipelineMode="false"/>
```

to my vwd.webinfo file.

This might or might not have had an effect on this but just putting it out there incase this helps someone else.